# Ruby on rails: can't cast Hash to string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Now I trying to create a login form but when I run my code, it throws: `[can't cast Hash to string]`
How can I resolve that?

tbluser Model

```
class Tbluser < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.primary_key = "username"
    def self.login(user,pass)
        if user and pass
            find(:conditions => ['username LIKE ? and password LIKE ?',"\#{user.to_s}","\#{pass.to_s}"])
        else
            find(:all)
        end
    end
end
```

Login Controller

```
class LoginController < ApplicationController
    protect_from_forgery with: :null_session
    def formlogin

    end
    def chekclogin
        @dn = Tbluser.login(params[:user],params[:pass])
        if @dn.blank?
            redirect_to:action => "error"
        else
            redirect_to:action => "success"
        end
    end
    def souc

    end
    def error

    end
end
```

Login Form View

```
<form class="login-form" accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/chekclogin" method="get">
      <%= text_field_tag :user, '', class: 'form-control', :placeholder => 'Username'%>
      <%= password_field_tag(:pass, "", placeholder: "Password")%>
      <button>login</button>
      <p class="message">Not registered? <a href="#">Create an account</a></p>
</form>
```

Comment: This is not a good login system - for example: you should never pass passwords via a GET. I'd recommend you consider using an authentication gem like Devise (https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) to handle user log in.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things here you can do to check what's going on:

1. Check the logs in `/logs/development.logs` when you make the request and you can see the params being passed to the controller.
2. In the controller itself put a `Rails.logger.info(params)` to see what the params are.

If you are still stuck, then if you can paste in the request log from your `development.log` I can take a look and help further.

As a side note, this is a good tutorial for basic login in rails 5: https://www.railstutorial.org/book/basic_login

Good luck!

Comment: i see my log that like above: 
Started GET "/chekclogin?user=admin&pass=admin" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-01-06 10:54:17 +0700
Processing by LoginController#chekclogin as HTML
  Parameters: {"user"=>"admin", "pass"=>"admin"}
admin
admin
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 5ms

TypeError (can't cast Hash to string):
  app/models/tbluser.rb:5:in `login'
  app/controllers/login_controller.rb:9:in `chekclogin'

Comment: It should be an space between redirect_to and :action. In your code seems like redirect_to:action is just one thing, could that be related?

Comment: yes this is right! in my code not an space between redirect_to and :action.
now i will try it
thank you

Comment: i changed to [ redirect_to :action => "error" ] but still can't cast Hash to string.

Comment: Check what the values of `user` and `pass` are in your `TblUser` model. Also, in your controller method `chekclogin` add a rails logger for your `params[:user]` and `params[:pass]`. Its a remote chance but you could also try accessing it as `params["user"]` and `params["pass"]`